# React Native Webview Google Analytics Tracking

Tags: android, react-native, google-analytics, cross-platform, react-native-webview

I have developed a cross-platform application, that consumes api. It's a News mobile application, and because there is also a website, i present single article as a Webview, from a url i took through api.

I want to track user activity, through GA already used from website, when a user open single articles as a webview. Is there a way to pass something through React Native Webview to identify activity come from mobile application?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a solution to this problem? Can you share that solution?